# Regex split extended CSV notation

Tags: regex, csv, data-transfer

I have a custom transport format that packages data up in the following format

[a:000,"name","field","field","field"]

I'm trying to split the individual lines out to get the first character after the left bracket and all the CSV values.
     a, 000, "name", "field", "field" etc...

I cobbled together

```
[^?,:\[\]]
```

This splits all the individual characters out not the colon/comma delimited fields.
I understand this won't accommodate commas within quotes.So it's clearly rubbish!

Embedded commas isn't really a huge issue as we're in control of the data at both ends so I could just escape them.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: It was Objective C using NSRegularExpression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to split on multiple characters and ignore some of them, try to match whatever you want to match. Since you didn't specify the implementation language I am posting this for Perl but you could apply it to any flavor which supports lookbehind and lookaheads.

```
while ($subject =~ m/(\w+(?=:)|(?<=:)\d+|(?<=,")[^"]*?(?="))/g) {
    # matched text = $&
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
# (\w+(?=:)|(?<=:)\d+|(?<=,")[^"]*?(?="))
# 
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+(?=:)|(?<=:)\d+|(?<=,")[^"]*?(?="))»
# Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\w+(?=:)»
# Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
# Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=:)»
# Match the character “:” literally «:»
# Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?<=:)\d+»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=:)»
# Match the character “:” literally «:»
# Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
# Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(?<=,")[^"]*?(?=")»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=,")»
# Match the characters “,"” literally «,"»
# Match any character that is NOT a “"” «[^"]*?»
# Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=")»
# Match the character “"” literally «"»
```

[See it working](http://ideone.com/sBZGa).

Comment: I love one-line regular expressions that come with 18-lines of documentation!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. It was for Objective C. I'll update if there are any issues with it!

Comment: Does anyone have any advice on how to modify the Perl regex for use within iOS, I'm not too familiar with regex's in Perl so after trying a few permutations i'm still banging my head!

Comment: Answering My own query:
As Obj C doesn't use the inline Regex control params "/g" etc...
It was just a case of removing them and escaping all the  slashes.
    NSString * const REGEX_CSV_SPLIT = @"(\\w+(?=:)|(?<=:)\\d+|(?<=,\")[^\"]*?(?=\"))";

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via regex of course, but the proper tool would most likely be a CSV parser. You can try this one by Dave DeLong for Objective C:

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment, as it contains only an external link.

Comment: Yes, but I could not add comments because I lacked reputation.